# Complex data for Chart.js in Blazor

Tags: charts, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating an `Blazor` application for marketing research. The application reads the data from an API and I want to display a quite complex graph based on `Chart.js`.

[image]

In this graph I have same groups of data and stack bar charts.

I can quite replicate the graph with `Chart.js` but I don't know how to use it properly in `Blazor`. I saw few components like **ChartJs.Blazor** and its fork, **Radzen** components or **Blazorize** but none of them has a demo for a graph like that.

Is there any example or demo how to create complex graphs like that?

Comment: I recommend you inspect them in Chrome, see how they're built, and then reproduce it using Blazor components.  There's nothing in there that especially needs to be done in JavaScript.  I don't understand what this data means, but if you can describe it a little more, maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have the `json` for this graph or I know how to create it. What I don't know is how to use `ChartJs.Blazor` or `Blazorize` to obtain that graph. All the example I found there are very simple, a bar or a line with data, but none with a complex graph like that

Comment: I'm probably giving you bad advice, as I don't know your level of programming experience.  I prefer to make all controls myself, including charts and graphs, so they work properly.  The first step is to unpack your JSON to a C# model.  If all the names match, that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I can do that but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I totally understand.  I absolutely HATE investing time in someone else's work, not knowing if I'll ever be able to get it to do what I want.  The time to create new components matters less to me than the insecurity and possible frustration of getting 95% of the way there and then failing due to some unexpected issue.

Comment: If you have some budget and don't have time to build your own, Syncfusion charts look pretty nice.  Here is a demo: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/chart/column?theme=bootstrap4